# Sheets API Glitch rounds number to 15 Significant Figures (Gspread)

Tags: api, google-sheets

When I make a Cell Update of an 18 Digits Number (A User ID), it is rounded off to 15 significant figures(sf), leaving the last 3 digits as 000 and leaving the answer in Scientific Form.

Example: When i set Cell A1 to `847996733362936884` programmatically, it ends up in the spread sheet as `8.48E+17` or `847996733362936000` in the Formula Bar

I don't think there's a need for a picture as the description above is self explainable.
If someone can get me an explanation that would be great!!!

I'm using Gspread (Sheets API v4) and have made sure that any other components that may be a hindrance to this problem have been eliminated.

Comment: It probably doesn't have enough precision for that many digits. Why are you storing a user id as a number anyway? Store it as text. You're not doing math with it.

Comment: I have already changed the format for the entire column MANUALLY to Plain text but somehow it still sets it as a number.

Comment: You say you set it programmatically, how is that accomplished?

Comment: not rly a glitch... you just need to format it as text string by wrapping it into doublequotes

Comment: It is a glitch if I put in a number and it rounds of off

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen.....I'm afraid you did not read the 4th paragraph of my post

Comment: @Fishball Noodles it is not a glitch

Comment: To be clear this is a problem with gspread rather than google sheets. Your manually forcing text formatting on a column will have no effect on values being pushed to a sheet by a 3rd party. The underlying format of the value is being inherited by the sheet from "gspread".

Comment: No, what I meant is can you please share the exact code you're using? Sorry for not making that clear.